# Apex test class method not working

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, failing-tests, apextestrunresult

I have the following method in my apex class:

```
@testVisible
private static Custon_Object_Case__c getExistingRecord(Messaging.InboundEmail email){
    List<String> referenceId = email.references;
    
    List<EmailMessage> prevmail = [SELECT RelatedToId from EmailMessage WHERE ThreadIdentifier =: referenceId];
    
    return [SELECT Id FROM Custon_Object_Case__c WHERE Id=: prevmail[0].RelatedToId];
}
```

This method simply returns the Id of the existing custom object record to which the incoming email belongs to. I wrote the following test method for but it is giving me error:

```
@IsTest
    static void getExistingRecordTest(){
       Custon_Object_Case__c testTTCase = new Custon_Object_Case__c();
        insert testTTCase;
        Messaging.InboundEmail email = new Messaging.InboundEmail() ;
         List<String> referenceId = email.references;
    
    EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage();
    email.FromAddress = 'test@abc.org';
    email.Incoming = True;
    email.ToAddress= 'test@test.com';
    email.ThreadIdentifier = referenceId[0];
    email.Subject = 'Test email';
    email.HtmlBody = 'Test email body';
    email.RelatedToId = testTTCase.Id;
    insert email;

        Test.startTest();
        Custom_Object_Case__c result = TT_CaseEmailService.getExistingRecord(email);
        Test.stopTest();
        EmailMessage relatedId = [SELECT RelatedToId FROM EmailMessage WHERE ThreadIdentifier =: referenceId]; 
        System.assertEquals(result.Id, testTTCase.Id);
        
    }
```

I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: so what is line 52 in the test class?

Comment: email.ThreadIdentifier = referenceId[0];

Answer (score 0):

@marjan : Above error is seen since you are not inserting `EmailMessage` records in test class.

Please try to insert `EmailMessage` record before `Test.startTest()` using below code :

```
EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage();
email.FromAddress = 'test@abc.org';
email.Incoming = True;
email.ToAddress= 'test@test.com';
email.ThreadIdentifier = referenceId[0];
email.Subject = 'Test email';
email.HtmlBody = 'Test email body';
email. RelatedToId = testTTCase.Id; // Link to your custom object record
insert email;
```

Try to follow best practises for Apex tests - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_best_practices.htm

Also , below line for assert is wrong in your test class :

```
System.assertEquals(relatedId.Id, testTTCase.Id);
```

You can assert the id returned by your method and the custom object inserted in the test method as below :

```
System.assertEquals(result.Id, testTTCase.Id);
```

Comment: I updated the question/code based on your suggestions but I still get the same error and test is failing.

Comment: Ok, @cropredy 's answer works

Comment: @Marjan : Do consider upvoting the answers if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here in the testmethod:

```
Messaging.InboundEmail email = new Messaging.InboundEmail() ;
List<String> referenceId = email.references;
```

the value of `email.references` is null so the value of the collection `referenceId` is also null

Thus, the line 52

```
email.ThreadIdentifier = referenceId[0];
```

fails because `referenceId` is null so there's no [0]th element

Since it looks like you are mocking an EmailMessage, line 52 should be something like

```
email.ThreadIdentifier = 'someValue';
```